# Qt dialog size policy

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog, qsizepolicy

I'm trying to set a size policy on a custom QDialog class I have created. The idea sounds pretty simple to me but it seems like I'm missing an obvious concept or paradigm of the Qt framework. I have created a LineDialog class below which contains 5 QRadioButtons. The reason they are all wrapped in an extra level of layout nesting is I will be adding other groups of buttons soon, assuming I can get one working. What I want is for the dialog to be at the minimum size when it opens, while still showing all of the radio buttons. The output I currently receive is a dialog the size of the entire computer screen with 5 radio buttons separated by equal amounts of vertical space in between along with tons of padding on the right side.

I have tried calling `setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minumum)` on both the `line_dialog` pointer in the calling class and all of the contents of LineDialog as can be seen by the commented out lines. However, I get compiler errors about how SetSizePoliy is a private function and cannot be called as I am doing. What's the correct way to do this?

(I have not gone through and properly released my heap memory so please disregard that)

**linedialog.cpp**

```
#include "linedialog.h"

LineDialog::LineDialog(QWidget * parent): QDialog(parent)
{
    QGridLayout *main_layout = new QGridLayout();
    QGroupBox *line_style_group = createLineStyleGroup();
    main_layout->addWidget(line_style_group, 0, 0);
    setLayout(main_layout);
}

QGroupBox *LineDialog::createLineStyleGroup() {
    QGroupBox *line_style_box = new QGroupBox(this);
    QButtonGroup *line_style_group = new QButtonGroup(this);

    QRadioButton *solid_line = new QRadioButton("Solid line", this);
    QRadioButton *dash_line = new QRadioButton("Dash line", this);
    QRadioButton *dot_line = new QRadioButton("Dot line", this);
    QRadioButton *dash_dot_line = new QRadioButton("Dash dot line", this);
    QRadioButton *dash_dot_dot_line = new QRadioButton("Dash dot dot line", this);

    //solid_line->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    //dash_line->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    //dot_line->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    //dash_dot_line->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    //dash_dot_dot_line->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum);

    /** logical line style button grouping */
    line_style_group->addButton(solid_line);
    line_style_group->addButton(dash_line);
    line_style_group->addButton(dot_line);
    line_style_group->addButton(dash_dot_line);
    line_style_group->addButton(dash_dot_dot_line);

    QVBoxLayout *line_style_box_layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    line_style_box_layout->addWidget(solid_line);
    line_style_box_layout->addWidget(dash_line);
    line_style_box_layout->addWidget(dot_line);
    line_style_box_layout->addWidget(dash_dot_line);
    line_style_box_layout->addWidget(dash_dot_dot_line);

    line_style_box->setLayout(line_style_box_layout);
    return line_style_box;
}
```

**calling class**

```
. . .
LineDialog *line_dialog = new LineDialog(this);
line_dialog.show();
. . .
```

Comment: I tried with your code and the dialog opens with the minimum possible size. No idea why it opens full screen in your case. May be you can use the same code in another project and see what happens.

Comment: You need to pass two arguments to QWidget::setSizePolicy, one for horizontal, one for vertical.

Comment: Frank Osterfeld is correct. `setSizePolicy` expects either one `QSizePolicy` object, or two `QSizePolicy::Policy` enumerations. You pass one `QSizePolicy::Policy` enum.

Comment: Wow I must have been reading the documentation wrong. Thank you for the help.